# could not load file or assembly microsoft.data.sqlclient despite already installing it by Nuget Package Manager

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, nuget, visual-studio-2022

I am a mentor to a few students teaching them how to create a database management system with Windows Forms with .Net 4.7.2 . A few students, have a problem when adding a new **Service Based Database** to their project. They get something like could not load file or assembly microsoft.data.sqlclient.

I've already made sure to download it via Nuget. I've also followed some tutorials online saying to delete the obj and bin folders, deleting the dll, rebuilding the solution, etc... Not even a fresh install of VS fixes the problem. About 3 students are facing the same problem and they're using Visual Studio 2022

Comment: Hi, what is the service based database you added, sql server database? How do you add them, please share more information. Also, please share some related screenshots. :)